# Spark Streaming custom receiver in "Python" (receive UDP over socket)

Tags: python, sockets, apache-spark, spark-streaming

The programming guide mentions that in Spark streaming, to develop custom receivers , it can be done in Java or Scala.
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-custom-receivers.html
However, I am wondering if a custom receiver can also be developed in **Python**.

Specifically what I am looking for is to receive **UDP data stream over a socket in *Python*.** I.e streaming data in UDP format from a device to a mentioned IP address and port number and I want to receive it in Spark streaming. If data is sent via TCP below simple code works fine, however not for UDP.

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="AppName")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
RowsData = ssc.socketTextStream(address, PortNumber)
```

A similar question was asked by me, but that was for *Scala*.
[Spark Scala UDP receive on listening port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320483/spark-scala-udp-receive-on-listening-port)

Or is it not possible to create a custom receiver in python or receive UDP packets in Python+Spark_Streaming ?

Comment: You cannot define receiver in Python, you can take Java implementation and write Python wrapper.

Comment: @zero323 Any link to a similar example shall be very helpful. I have never written a python wrapper before. Or even where I can start is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: [Spark source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/streaming/context.py#L258-L271) is a good place to start :) You can also take a look at the internal mllib API (https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1f31bdaef670dd43999613deae3620f4ddcd1fbf/python/pyspark/mllib/common.py#L92).